# "Unresolved External" error in Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I am making my first foray into programming for windows after writing Linux console applications elusively. I have written a simple "Hello world" program to familiarize myself with Visual C++ (2010 Express) and am receiving an error (listed below) when I attempt to Build Solution.

The Code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL,
               L"Hello World!",
               L"Just another Hello World program!",
               MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

The Error:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>\\lc01users\users\users\grossw\docs\visual studio 2010\Projects\practice_2\Debug\practice_2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have seen this question asked many times here on StackOverflow, but the almost always correct solution of changing the Subsystem from "windows" to "console" seems to only apply to people whose programs are using a simple  message to print to the console instead of a windows message box; I tried changing it but I get the same exact error either way.

Note: with the exception of not using a pre-compiled header, all of the Visual C++ Express 2010 settings are default.

I have received several warnings about asking poor questions, and I know things are strict here for a reason, but I hope this is more along the lines of what you're looking for :)

Comment: You can use `MessageBox` in both console and Windows applications. Anyway, I'm not sure why, but it seems that for once, VS wants you to have a `main` function, not `WinMain`, in a Windows application. Did you change the entry point?

Comment: I did not change anything other than to set the "Precompiled Header" option to "Not Using Precompiled Headers". I ran it with that option also at default (and including the StdAfx.h header file) and got the same error.

Comment: It's not like you need `WinMain` here, so changing it to `int main()` should work fine, but while I found it unlikely, I kind of have to go with the answer below that you just hit console application when creating the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you had a "Console application" selected when you created your project (in step 3 below).

When creating your project make sure to create it as follows:

1. Project type: Win32
2. Project sub-type: Win32 Project (or console application, as needed)
3. Create an EMPTY project but make sure the type is set to "Windows application"

Once this is done "add" a new source file (.cpp) and put your code into it.

Hit "F7" and you should have your program sucessfuly built.

Comment: Perfect. This did the trick. There must have been some extraneous "template" files I didn't see that were causing mischief. Thanks!

Comment: This article could prove useful to your initial Windows application writing needs:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx

Comment: True, but ignore everything it says about `TCHAR` and `_T` and all that and stick with the wide strings you're using now. It's not the greatest C++ to begin with, but style is easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

#include
 < windows.h>

int main()
{

```
MessageBox(NULL,

           L"Hello World!",

           L"Just another Hello World program!",

           MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

return 0;
```

}